# change the button text in datagridview when clicking

Tags: c#, button, text

I have an unbound `DataGridViewButtonColumn` and I want to change the text on each button(and each line) after the user performs an action (to mark the process as in progress or ready ).  How do I change the button text in one row without affecting every row? because i tried to use the name of the cell but then all the lines are affected

I have tried this

```
dataGridView1[e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex].Value = "new button text";
dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "ABCD";
ColumnButton.Text = "in progress";
```

Comment: Is your button text bound to the underlying datasource row?

Comment: my button is created using the datagridview assistant

Answer (score 0):

You said it's an unbound `DataGridView`, but I'm not sure how you're adding rows. I'm assuming that you're creating an instance of `DataGridViewRow` then adding a `DataGridViewButtonCell` to the `Cells` property for the button column?

If setting the text of the column (`ColumnButton.Text = "in progress"`) changes the text of all the cells then it sounds like you're setting `UseColumnTextForButtonValue` to true on the `DataGridViewButtonCell`. If that property is set to true, then changing the `Value` on the cell won't update the button's text.

When you're adding rows, just set the `Value` on the `DataGridViewButtonCell` to `ColumnButton.Text` to default it to the column's text. Then `dataGridView1[e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex].Value = "new button text";` should work.

```csharp
private void PopulateDataGridView()
{
   // Assuming I have a DataGridView named dataGridView1 with only one column
   // which is a DataGridViewButtonColumn named ButtonColumn that I set up in
   // the "Add Columns" or "Edit Columns" window...
   var row = new DataGridViewRow();
   var btnCell = new DataGridViewButtonCell();

   // Instead of btnCell.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true, do this to set the
   // text of the button to the text of the column by default.
   btnCell.Value = ButtonColumn.Text;

   row.Cells.Add(btnCell);   

   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(
   object sender, 
   DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = "Loading...";
}
```

Comment: yes i created the daratgridview then i added the column using the assistant and also created the cellbutton and set this UseColumnTextForButtonValue to true otherwise the text will not be shown . but i tried to edit it to false bt still did not work i was trying since the morning all he codes that i could find but it doesnt work

Comment: When you create the `DataGridViewButtonCell`, instead of setting `UseColumnTextForButtonValue` to true, just set the `Value` property to `ButtonCell.Text`. If it still doesn't work, which event are you handling? You need to handle `CellContentClick` and not `CellClick`.